# Can't boot Windows 7 after Ubuntu 14 install

Tags: boot

I decided to try Ubuntu for the first time and thought I would install it on my usb backup drive. It wouldn't let me partition my win7 drive.  After what appeared to be a successful installation,  I restarted and got a 'no such device' error. I googled the problem and every time I try to get grub to the normal mode it says missing ') ' token. What does this mean? I really need to get back into my windows 7 as this is my only computer. I dont have a recovery disk because I just bought this pc from someone else. Thanks for reading. I typed this up with my phone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score 0):

What did you do during the installation?

Do you still have a windows partition on that disks? You can use the live cd/usb access gparted and check it out.

Comment: I had to use WinXP to reinstall some version of windows then I made a win 7 repair disk so I got back into my files. Don't think I want to use ubuntu now though. I am pretty scared my pc is gonna break on me now. I tried using the live cd thing and it wouldn't even let me get online. Tried using the browser and all it wold say is cant  find any wevsite. This is the same connection I used with windows 7. Completely turned me away from linux and I was expecting good things.